# [JAVA]I converted a LinkedList of type Integer into an Array.How to determine the size of the array after the conversion

Tags: java, arrays, collections, linked-list, size

I created a LinkedList and added the below elements to it.

```
List<Integer> integers = new LinkedList<>();
integers.add(0);
integers.add(45);
integers.add(95);
integers.add(5);
integers.add(12);

Integer[] arr = integers.toArray(new Integer[3]);
    System.out.println(arr.length);
for(int c:arr)  {
  System.out.println(c);
}
```

The length of the array is printed as 5,when I have restricted the length of the array to 3.All the Elements are displayed in the output.

And then if I try adding 6th element to the array it gives

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

How is the Length of the Array being determined here? Why the anomalous behaviour of Array?

Comment: Unrelated: integer is a **terrible** name for a list of Integer. Call the list "wholeNumbers", or maybe "integers" - but express that it is about **plural**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be expected, just read the javadoc for [List.toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])):

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. **Otherwise**, a **new array** is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the **size of this list**.

Thus: when you use this method it will figure: the list has **5** elements, not 3. So it creates an array with room for 5 items, and thus `arr.lenght` is 5.

And of course, array indexes go from 0 to 4, so when you go for `arr[5]` you are "one off" - out of the boundaries of the array.

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 0):

That line:

```
Integer[] arr = integer.toArray(new Integer[3]);
```

can be even replaced with

```
Integer[] arr = integer.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

you could think that array will have length of... `0`?

Yet the argument `Integer[0]` s only needed for a **type** recognition for the array you are converting to.

Therefore, you will get the same result: integer list converted to an array of `integer` list size, which is `5`,

And since its length is `5`, you can access only indexes of `0,1,2,3,4`, so 6th is clearly **out of bounds** of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your intenssion is to just have the first 3 elements in your new array you can do something like this :

```
Integer[] arr2 = integer.stream().limit(3).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split an answer into the 2 topics

#### List.toArray behavior

This is not something specific to a LinkedList, but to all List collections in Java. According to Java Doc for the method `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)` of both [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) interface and [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#toArray(T[])) implementation, the behavior is following:

1. If the list *fits* in the specified array `a`, it is returned
   therein
2. If the list *does not fit* in passed array `a`, the newly-allocated array of required size is returned of the same
   runtime type as `a`

General Examples using `java.util.Arrays` utility class:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,45,95,5,12); //creates a list of 5 elements

Integer[] enoughCapacity = new Integer[list.size()]; // the same as new Integer[5]
Integer[] exported = list.toArray(enoughCapacity);
System.out.println(enoughCapacity == exported); //prints 'true' because both references initial and exported point to the same array

Integer[] smallerCapacity = new Integer[3];
Integer[] anotherExported = list.toArray(smallerCapacity); // here only runtime type of smallerCapacity array will be used by toArray
System.out.println(smallerCapacity == anotherExported); //prints 'false' because anotherExported is newly-allocated array of list size 
System.out.println(smallerCapacity.length); // prints '3' thus smallerCapacity points to a different array and remains unchanged
System.out.println(anotherExported.length); // prints '6'
```

#### Adding extra element to an array

Array, once allocated,  cannot have more elements than its length. That's why you're getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to add 6-th element to the array of size 5
It is still possible to expand array capacity by using

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[5];
array = Arrays.copyOf(array,6); //this "expands" capacity to 6
array[5] = 42; // remember, indexing starts from 0 and 6-th element has index of 5
System.out.println(array.length); //prints '6'
```

but please note, that `Arrays.copyOf` ([Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int))) actually is a shortcut for allocating brand new array and copying content of old array into the new one. Which seems to be quite expensive comparing to working with corresponding Java Collections which are well designed for adding new elements, e.g. `LinkedList`